# I'm trying to make sub category in admin panel cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->Category->create();
    if ($this->Category->save($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The category has been saved', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The category could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
    }
}
$parentCategories = $this->Category->ParentCategory->find('list');

$this->set(compact('parentCategories'));
```

this code is working good I'm getting the categories name in `$parentCategories` but in the add function its not fetching the data in the field

[image]

Comment: Do you have in your model a relation from this Category to same category? If yes you must load in a variable your categories (already created) then in your form.ctp edit.ctp or whatever $this->Form->input('category', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $variableThatHasCategoryesListedInController]);

Comment: <?php
  echo $this->Form->input('parentCategories');
  echo $this->Form->input('name');
  echo $this->Form->input('is_active',array('checked'=>true));
  
  
 ?> 
i tried this and working similar to that you suggested

Comment: Great, do you need another help? :D